# How to form additional values to mvc action by using Ajax.BeginForm MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to know how can I pass the additional data to mvc action with Ajax.BeginForm? I did not find any Ajax Option to pass additional params like we can pass when we use $.ajax. Can someone please suggest how can I pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { /*OPTIONS for example*/ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxCreateAdminForm" }))
{
//Form with inputs
}
```

AjaxOptions have many opt. which you can use. In this page you can check this: [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { name="test" }, new AjaxOptions { /*OPTIONS for example*/ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxCreateAdminForm" }))
    {
    //Form with inputs
    }
```

All types of helper Ajax.BeginForm calls are describe in MSDN ->[Ajax.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: I want something similar to this data:"{'name': test}", how would I pass data parameter to mvc action

Comment: If I understand you, You dont want use AjaxOptions to customise ajax form. You only want send extra date to action in controller and you of course can :)

Comment: Yes, right. Please let me know how would I do that with ajax.beginform ?

Comment: I put this in my anwer, under EDIT label. :)

Comment: Here you are sending "name=test", static data that you know when you are writing the code, but what if you want to send something from an input, how to include that as an extra parameter?